# Update Pandas within Spyder

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, spyder, pythonxy

I use Spyder as the IDE to program python. Pandas 0.13.1 had been installed before. There is an attribute error while I was programming: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'weekday'. I figured out that it was a Pandas version problem. I tried to upgrade the Pandas. So I downloaded the most updated Anacoda from the official website and got it installed. I checked the Pandas version from the Spyder, it still showed as 0.13.1. Can anyone please help me with it ? How to get Pandas updated to 0.18.1 or above ? Thanks.

Comment: in win use in `cmd` `conda update pandas`

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for your comments, but it will only update the pandas for the windows, the Pandas called by the Pythonxy--Spyder is still 0.16.1. Showed as below:                                                                  In[6]: import pandas as pd

In[7]: pd.__version__
Out[8]: '0.16.2'

Comment: Please remove PythonXY and only use Anaconda.